# Python: How to replace only 0 values in a column by multiplication of 2 columns in Dataframe with a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

Here is my Dataframe:

```
df={'pack':[2,2,2,2], 'a_cost':[10.5,0,11,0], 'b_cost':[0,6,0,6.5]}
```

It should look like this:

[image: this]

At this point you will find that *a_cost* and *b_cost* columns have 0s where other column has a value. I would like my function to follow this logic...

```
for i in df.a_cost:
    if i==0:
       b_cost(column):value *(multiply) pack(column):value
       replace 0 with this new multiplied value (example: 6.0*2=12)
for i in df_b.cost:
    if i==0:
       a_cost(column):value /(divide) pack(column):value
       replace 0 with this new divided value (example: 10.5/2=5.25)
```

I can't figure out how to write this logic successfully... Here is the expected output:

[image: Dataframe]

Output in code:

```
df={'pack':[2,2,2,2], 'a_cost':[10.5,12.0,11,13.0], 'b_cost':[5.25,6,5.50,6.5]}
```

Help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'pack':[2,2,2,2], 'a_cost':[10.5,0,11,0], 'b_cost':[0,6,0,6.5]})

df['a_cost'] = np.where(df['a_cost']==0, df['pack']*df['b_cost'], df['a_cost'])
df['b_cost'] = np.where(df['b_cost']==0, df['a_cost']/df['pack'], df['b_cost'])

print (df)
#pack  a_cost  b_cost
#0     2    10.5     5.25
#1     2    12.0     6.0
#2     2    11.0     5.50
#3     2    13.0     6.5
```

Comment: Hi! So, you said that .apply should be used as last resort... would you say that in case i work with a dataframe with hundreds of thousands of observations - would your approach would be less resourceful? On the side note, it seems that b_cost has not changed in your output

Comment: @DGomonov It will be faster in terms of speed. Also edited the output of my answer as I did not run the next line to test haha.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC,

```
df.loc[df.a_cost.eq(0), 'a_cost'] = df.b_cost * df.pack
df.loc[df.b_cost.eq(0), 'b_cost'] = df.a_cost / df.pack
```

You can also play with `mask` and `fillna`:

```
df['a_cost'] = df.a_cost.mask(df.a_cost.eq(0)).fillna(df.b_cost * df.pack)
df['b_cost'] = df.b_cost.mask(df.b_cost.eq(0)).fillna(df.a_cost / df.pack)
```

*Update* as commented, you can use `other` in `mask`:

```
df['a_cost'] = df.a_cost.mask(df.a_cost.eq(0), other=df.b_cost * df.pack)
```

Also note that the second filtering is not needed once you already fill `0` in columns `a_cost`. That is, we can just do:

```
df['b_cost'] = df.a_cost / df.pack
```

after the first command in both methods.

Output:

```
   pack  a_cost  b_cost
0     2    10.5    5.25
1     2    12.0    6.00
2     2    11.0    5.50
3     2    13.0    6.50
```

Comment: I'm just reading this quickly, but cant' you use the second argument of `mask` instead of `fillna`?

Comment: @rafaelc that is indeed very true. Never used `other` in `mask` before.

Comment: @DGomonov IMHO, `where(series)` and `mask(~series)` are the same. For your case, I feel that `mask` is more readable.

Comment: @DGomonov if you are asking `np.where` as in ycx's answer and `mask()`, I'd say `np.where` is a bit faster. But I prefer `loc` approach since it is more readable to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['a_pack'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['b_cost']*x['pack'] if x['a_cost'] == 0 and x['b_cost'] != 0 else x['a_cost'], axis = 1)

df['b_pack'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['a_cost']/x['pack'] if x['b_cost'] == 0 and x['a_cost'] != 0 else x['b_cost'], axis = 1)
```

Comment: That works! Thank you, I definitely need to get more comfortable with lambda functions

Comment: Do note that `.apply` should only be used as a last resort generally` as it is very resource intensive

Comment: @ycx AFAIK, use of `.apply` is discourage mostly because of its slow speed (essentially equivalent to a `for` loop), not because of resource constraint.

Comment: @QuangHoang That was what I meant to say but typed out differently. You are correct.

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks for breakdown. However in yours case you use .where or .mask - what is better if I am working with a big dataset?